# What does this symbol mean in the "Collector" research?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the temporary research there is a challenge to catch specific pokemon.

Some are normal, some are event, but there is one that I'm not sure what it means.

[image]

What does this symbol mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That symbol means you can complete the research task by evolving a Bunnelby into a Diggersby

Comment: Adding to this, the symbol matches the Scientist Medal symbol used, where the Medals are rewarded for evolving Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol means the task can be completed by evolution and additionally, the symbol matches the Scientist Medal, where medals are rewarded for evolving Pokemon.

Comment: Not only does this not add anything that Wondercricket already covered, but the second half of your answer is almost word -for-word the same as BGamer's comment on the other answer.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is just a grammatical rewording of Wondercricket's answer and associated comment.  Questions can be flagged as duplicates; answers?